# Nodejs file upload

Tags: node.js, formidable

And I am getting this error :
var oldpath = files.filetoupload.path;
TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined

In this code:

```
var http = require('http');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if (req.url == '/fileupload') {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
      var oldpath = files.filetoupload.path;
      var newpath = 'C:/Users/Your Name/' + files.filetoupload.name;
      fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.write('File uploaded and moved!');
        res.end();
      });
 });
  } else {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write('<form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
    res.write('<input type="file" name="fil`enter code here`etoupload"><br>');
    res.write('<input type="submit">');
    res.write('</form>');
    return res.end();
  }
}).listen(8080);
```

Using the w3c shool website:https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_uploadfiles.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your input type file.
You need to give it a name: filetoupload

```
<input type="file" name="filetoupload">
```